# Counting number of days in specific range and with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

my problem is to create a query based on a table which has structure  of datetime_value and value.
The records are 1 hour intervals with a value.
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a query which will return number of days in a specified period, grouped by year.
For example, my input parameters are: start_date, end_date and type.
start_date and end_date indicate the range of dates to search in
type indicates type of division for period:

- if number in range(1,12) then number of days in particular month - I managed to do it
- if empty '' then number of days in year - also done
- if (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) then number of days in specified quarter:

  -Q1 - months 6, 7, 8

  -Q2 - months 9, 10, 11

  -Q3 - months 12 and from next year: 1, 2 - the biggest issue!!!

  -Q4 - months 3, 4, 5

So for example when I specify:

```
SET @start_date = 2017-12-20 00:00:00
SET @end_date = 2019-04-30 23:59:59
SET @type = 'Q3'
```

I want to receive number of days in date range grouped by period:

```
period     |   num_of_days
Q3_17_18   |   71 (dec 2017 from start_date + jan, feb 2018 = 12+31+28)
Q3_18_19   |   90 (dec 2018 + jan, feb 2019 = 31+31+28)
```

For other quarters it's easy -  I just use month(datetime_value) IN (6,7,8) etc. But he main issue is Q3 because it consists of months from different years.
Below source table:

```
datetime_value        |  value  | 
2018-04-21 00:01:00   |   100   |
2018-04-21 00:02:00   |   400   |
2018-04-21 00:03:00   |   200   |
...
2019-02-03 00:16:00   |   100   |
2018-04-21 00:17:00   |   500   |
```

Comment: The best approach to this would first be to create a calendar table with attributes that specify which year and quarter each day belongs to. I assume you have some sort of financial year starting 01-Jun each year. Once you have this, performing the filtering and aggregation to get the count of days in each period is a piece of cake. Trying to perform complex date logic without a pre-formed and pre-verified calendar table is almost always a prescription for pain.

Comment: @Steve it's an approach. Certainly. But it's overstating the case to suggest that it's 'best'.

Comment: "But he main issue is Q3 because it consists of months from different years" - And what exactly is the problem? `month(datetime_value) IN (1,2,12)` should work as well as for other quarters. What is your query for Q1?

Comment: @Strawberry, I find it is the best general solution. Date logic can become enormously complex and subtle. Interleaved with a specific query, the logic often becomes unverifiable. And in nearly all cases of custom calendars, they are applicable to more than one query.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel the problem is that I need to sum days in (1,2,12) but 1 and 2 don't come from the same year as 12 but from next year

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sample data od the table with datetimes with 1 hour interval, what I need to get is period name (like Q3-17-18) and sum of days in this period for specified date range

Comment: I still don't see a problem with `month(datetime_value) IN (1,2,12)` - since the year is irrelevant for this part. You might have an issue somewhere else - like `GROUP BY year(datetime_value)` - But you did't post your query. One fix could be `GROUP BY year(datetime_value + INTERVAL 1 month)`. But I also don't even understand, why you try to solve that issue in SQL. If you know there is data for every day in the table, I wouldn't touch it - And just use `datediff`, or what ever your language supports.

Comment: Try to be more clear on what you want, and for these kind of problems https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/&ved=2ahUKEwiToorU1aXiAhXB3KQKHUSHDKcQFjAaegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0EZkNriBZQNYM5DXSwAIzU may be helpful

Comment: @GJCode I thought it was pretty clear what he wants - he wants logic which treats June as the start of each year, numbers the quarters accordingly, and allows him to count the number of days that fall into each quarter when the source data is filtered to a range. He already provided examples of source data, desired output, and a fair explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cornisto, I'm assuming you have at least one row in the table for every day in the period concerned. To reduce the hourly rows and get one row per day, you can first:

```
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(datetime_value), MONTH(datetime_value), DAY(datetime_value)
```

To get the month-of-the-year based on June being the first month of each year:

```
((((MONTH(datetime_value) + 7) - 1) % 12) + 1) AS mth_of_yr
```

NB: To adjust to June being month 1, I'm adding 7 rather than subtracting 5 in order to prevent a negative value being presented to the MOD operator. So given June which would normally be month 6 of the year but which we want to be month 1, we add 7 which results 13. We subtract 1, then MOD 12 will result 0, and then add 1 to produce the desired final result of (month) 1. I'm accustomed to working in one-based, rather than zero-based, numbering with dates.

To get the quarter-of-the-year based on the same June-based month number:

```
(((mth_of_yr - 1) DIV 3) + 1) AS qtr_of_yr
```

To get the current year based on the start of the year being 01-Jun each year:

```
(YEAR(datetime_value) - IF(mth_of_yr > 7, 1, 0))
```

This will ensure that months Jan-May of the following year, are treated as belonging to the previous year.

As I said in the comments to your question, I would advise you perform all this logic separately and create a calendar/date table. With such a table already to hand, your actual query (and any others which employ this June-based calendar) will be greatly simplified.

Comment: Thank you very much! that is exactly what I was thinking about. I need to consider making a calendar table because I for now I can't say if it will be useful for other queries or not. Anyway I'm very grateful for your explanation

Comment: @cornisto, if you're happy then don't forget to mark as answered! :) And if you need more help just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in quite different way by flagging period based on input parameter. Here is my solution:

```
SET @start_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
SET @end_date = '2019-05-30 23:59:59';
SET @period = 'Q3';

SELECT days_by_period.period AS period1, COUNT(*) AS total_days 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        date(datetime_value) AS load_date,
        max(the_value) AS max_value,
        (CASE 
            WHEN @period LIKE 'Q%' AND MONTH(datetime_value) IN (6, 7, 8) THEN CONCAT('Q1_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2), '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2) + 1)
            WHEN @period LIKE 'Q%' AND MONTH(datetime_value) IN (9, 10, 11) THEN CONCAT('Q2_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2), '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2) + 1)
            WHEN @period LIKE 'Q%' AND MONTH(datetime_value) = 12 THEN CONCAT('Q3_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2), '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2) + 1)
            WHEN @period LIKE 'Q%' AND MONTH(datetime_value) IN (1, 2) THEN CONCAT('Q3_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2) - 1, '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2))
            WHEN @period LIKE 'Q%' AND MONTH(datetime_value) IN (3, 4, 5) THEN CONCAT('Q4_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2) - 1, '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2))
            WHEN @period = 'YEAR' THEN CONCAT('Y_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2))
            ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(datetime_value, '%b')), '_', RIGHT(YEAR(datetime_value), 2))
        END) AS period
    FROM test_db.my_table
    WHERE datetime_value >= @start_date
    AND datetime_value <= @end_date
    GROUP BY date(datetime_value)) AS days_by_period
GROUP BY period1
```

Comment: Does that produce correct results for December results though? To my eye it appears to treat December as falling in the year previous, when it is only January onwards that need that treatment. If so, that would return me to my original point about the error-proneness of trying to combine date logic inline with a query, instead of formulating a solution to date logic or defining a calendar, that can be verified separately from the business logic it serves.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake when copying the code, now it's correct